# Updating Wordpress Table after a Google Sheet Update

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, wordpress-rest-api

I am currently looking into helping someone using Wordpress and Google Sheets. Essentially, they use Google Sheets data as a backend and Wordpress will display that as a table in a post.

The only issue is this data is refreshed every five mins by an add-on they are using. However, it would be best if the data was updated real time. I am a full stack developer, but not overly familiar with Word Press, is there a way to 1) get the table data to update in real time? Or 2) have the table data loaded on page refresh, like a typical UI to backend service call would?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) function or the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) at any time to update the content of any page, or if the table is stored in an option, use [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/).

Then, it's just a matter of whether you want to scan for changes on the server side, or can send a webhook of some kind when the row is updated.

I can think of a few options.

1. Set up a Cron Job at the server level to check the google sheet for changes, and use either function above to update the table. *I don't really recommend that for this because it won't be "live" updates, and may run more (or less) often than it needs to*.
2. See if the "addon" can post the updated row to the WordPress REST api (or custom function handler)
3. Use one of the [Sheets Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) (`onEdit`?) in the sheet's Apps Script to fire a remote request to your site with the updated row's value (or the whole sheet?) and update it via the REST API or custom function handler with `wp_update_post` or `update_option`.
4. Use a third party "webhook tool" to hook the Sheet to your site. A tool like [Zapier](https://zapier.com) or [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) comes to mind.

I'd probably lean towards number 3 as it lets you tie straight into the Google Sheet with Apps Script, and POST just the updated row to your WordPress' site via the API, which provides the following benefits:

• Updates your site "live", as soon as an update is made to the sheet
• Doesn't require server-side set up
• Low amount of data transmitted over the wire
• No needless checks/requests
• No other third-party tools required